# LoadTesting ClickOnce Application with Load Runner 11.5

Tags: 64-bit, clickonce, load-testing, performance-testing, loadrunner

We're supposed to carryout Performance Testing on a 64 bit standalone desktop application on 64 bit OS built around .Net 4.0 and HTML5 with WPF & WCF(it's a ClickOnce Application)..

While using LoadRunner 11.5 for recording, application is NOT launching in the foreground but in the background, the respective process is running in Task Manager.

We've Googled and found out that a ClickOnce Application cannot be recorded using the general installation path(E:\xxx\xxxx\xxxx.exe)

Possible workaround might be going forward with the .exe file in the Deployment Folder. But we're still unable to launch the application using VUGEN via the exe file in the DeploymentFolder path: "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\obscure_dir_name1\obscure_dir_name1\ "

Please find the links below for further info on ClickOnce-VUGEN problem.

> [Recording ClickOnce Application in VUGEN](http://eyeontesting.com/questions/1779/how-to-use-loadrunner-to-record-an-application-tha.html)
>
> [MSDN Forums on ClickOnce Application](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/7a519190-1477-49dd-b9c8-d194e3040de0)

Answer (score 0):

What is the application (or presentation) layer protocol communication mechanism for this application?    (see OSI model definitions for clarity on application of presentation layer protocols)

You will already have an issue regarding a 64 bit application for recording as vugen is a 32 bit application and hooking is not going to effectively cross the WOW32 subsystem barrier for the 32 bit control of a 64 bit application.   See release notes regarding the recording of 64 bit applications

Comment: Hi James,
The application uses HTTPS protocol. As mentioned above we've reinstalled the Application with proper deployment folder and retried launching with LoadRunner but in vain.

we've tried two other tools Seapine LoadComplete, QA Wizard Pro but this time we were able to launch and record the application but while replaying it, we're getting HTTP 401-Unauthorized Access Error. 

Some more info on Application:
The application directly launches. Doesn't need login.

Can program arguments cause problems while launching via LoadComplete/QA Wizard Pro?

Comment: YOu have windows integrated security.   You will need a web_set_user statement in your script along with a setting enabled in the run time settings to educate LoadRunner to take advantage of the Windows integrated security layer instead of using the web Turboload technology.   Look for a setting in your run time settings for WinInet and ensure that it is enabled.   Read up on the web_set_user() and its integration into LoadRunner.

Comment: Hi James, we have tried your suggestions but we were not able to launch the application.

Parallely we tried accessing the ThinClient version of the application via LoadRunner 11.5.

We're getting this error "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'"

Comment: And enabling winINET had zero effect?  Did you try this on the native platform for Load Generators, Win32?

Comment: It did not have any positive effect. In fact it's 64bit application hosted on a 64bit environment.

We're now focucssing on WebServices Protocol with which we're getting the above mentioned error.

The following info on WsHttpBinding might help.

<wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="proposal"maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>

Comment: HTTP has no required basis in 64 bit.  Once you have stripped the conversation with the next upstream component there is no platform dependency for execution.   You could take this HTTP stream to Win32 for representation or to LINUX (if you did not need Windows Integrated Security).   Back end platforms do not generate distinct HTML based upon the number of bits on the processor or operating system design